# Getting ArgoCD and BuildKite notify each other

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, continuous-delivery, buildkite

Sorry, this may sound a bit vague, but is there any way for the following make the following scenario happen?

BuildKite builds a project
Argo CD deploys 
BuildKite runs the test against the latest deployment.

Is there a way for BuildKite to kick off the tests once it finds out that Argo CD has deployed the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have much Argo CD experience directly, but after doing some digging it sounds like you'll need to add an Argo CD PostSync hook to your resource:
https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/resource_hooks/

And from within the PostSync hook, you can start a new Buildkite build using:
https://buildkite.com/docs/apis/rest-api/builds#create-a-build

Hope that helps!

Comment: Another way to integrate Argo CD and Buildkite is described here: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/ci_automation/

Buildkite might trigger sync explicitly using `argocd cli`, wait for app to be synced and healthy and then run tests:

`argocd app sync <myApp> && argocd app wait <myApp>`

Comment: How to trigger a buildkite pipeline after ArgoCD Deployment